# How I can get a value of a cell from access database in C#?

Tags: c#, database

I want to get a value of a cell from access database where value of "fdne1" column is textBox1.text
in other words I dont know "statment" code in below code what should be
my database columns are fdne1, fee

```
string statement =??????????? */Select * From Table2 where fdne1 valve is textBox1.text
OleDbCommand MyOleDbComm2 = new OleDbCommand();
                        ObjConn2.Open();
                        MyOleDbComm2.CommandText =
                            "UPDATE Table2 " +
                            "SET fee="+ statment +
                            " Where(Table2.fdne1)='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
                        MyOleDbComm2.Connection = ObjConn2;
                        MyOleDbComm2.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        ObjConn2.Close();
```

My database is access and has 2 tables ,table2  have 2 columns I want to get value of "fee" column in a row that "fdne1" value is somthing like textbox1.text and put it to a string or convert it to int then I do some mathematic processes on it and put the new value on database
I can edit database but I want value of the cell that I said
Sorry for bad English :)

Comment: WHAT? can you clarify a little bit more on what you are trying to do

Comment: Ýou make me sad, please check your code on sql injection.

Comment: My database is access and has 2 tables ,table2  have 2 columns I want to get value of "fee" column in a row that "fdne1" value is somthing like textbox1.text and put it to a string or convert it to int then I do some mathematic processes on it ande put the new value on database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should know that SQL has some statements like :

```
Select to select value(s) from table
Update to update value(s) from table
...
```

If you want to get the value of one cell in the table you should use a select  statement .

Like this: Select "your column" from "your table" where "your condition to filter the column"

be aware that the result might return more than one value as for your condition.
If you want to update a value in the table then use an update statement like this:

Update "your table" set "your column=new value" where "your condition to find the value inside the column"

Please be more explicit and I will provide more info.

If I have to I right then I can try to give you some code sample:

```
OleDbCommand MyOleDbComm2 = new OleDbCommand();
ObjConn2.Open();

MyOleDbComm2.CommandText = "Select fee from table2 " + 
                           " Where Table2.fdne1='" + textBox1.Text + "'";
MyOleDbComm2.Connection = ObjConn2;

var result= MyOleDbComm2.ExecuteScalar();

ObjConn2.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't use Access Query Designer and then copy and paste the SQL ?